# Changes don't appear to fire for computed bindings

Tags: binding, polymer

If I create an observer for all changes on a structure object, the observer will get called unless the the binding is a change to a value in a computed binding.

Is this the expected behavior? If so, how can I capture changes to the property in the computed binding?

Example:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<dom-module id="binding-test">

<template>
    <paper-input label="Not computed" value="{{myObject.prop1}}"></paper-input>
    <paper-input label="Computed" value="{{computeIt(myObject.prop2)}}"></paper-input>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is:"binding-test",

        properties: {
            myObject: {
                type: Object,
                notify: true,
                value: {
                    prop1: 1,
                    prop2: 2
                }
            }
        },

        observers: [
            'somethingChanged(myObject.*)'
        ],

        somethingChanged: function(changeRecord) {
            // This code is never executed when the Computed input field is changed
            console.log(changeRecord);
        },

        computeIt: function(value) {
            return value;
        }
    });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong with this one but I think *computed binding* is **one-way**, same as *computed property*.

If you really want to notify the change on a *paper-input* like that, you can listen to the `value-changed` event and then do a `notifyPath`/`set` on `"myObject.prop2"`.

```
<paper-input label="Computed" on-value-changed="valueChanged" value="{{computeIt(myObject.prop2)}}"></paper-input>

valueChanged: function(e) {
    this.set("myObject.prop2", e.detail.value);
}
```

Check out this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oVJAQbN0BmjgfeKuCLej?p=preview).

---

### Update

I think there's a better solution for your problem. Instead of converting values back and forth using expressions/filters, `paper-input` now allows you to define `prefix` and `suffix` like the following -

```
<paper-input label="revenue" type="number">
  <div prefix>$</div>
</paper-input>

<paper-input label="email">
  <div suffix>@email.com</div>
</paper-input>
```

You can even define complex inputs like this (you will need to create your own `date-input` element though) -

```
<paper-input-container auto-validate>
   <label>Social Security Number</label>
   <ssn-input class="paper-input-input"></ssn-input>
   <paper-input-error>SSN invalid!</paper-input-error>
</paper-input-container>
```

Code samples above are taken from [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?view=demo:demo/index.html). You can read more about it on Polymer's official website over [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input).

Comment: Justin, Thanks for taking a look at this issue. Yes, I think you are right that the binding is one way. However, I am not sure if listening for the value changed event solves the problem because while the event includes the changed value it does not include anything about the model object that I need to update. I could have one of these valueChanged methods for each property that uses a computed binding but even that doesn't work if my binding is inside a dom-repeat template - I wouldn't know which item had changed (well, maybe using ids on the UI elements).

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that the property could be dynamic, so this won't work. But my question is, why does it have to be a computed property in the first place when direct editing is required?

Comment: Justin, I have lots of cases where I need to show formatted model values in input controls. For example, the model objects in my application store money as long values but I need to display the values in the input fields with currency symbols (commas, decimal place, etc). I have the same sort of thing for dates and other values. I think this is very common. In Polymer 0.5, this was well handled by expressions and filters (e.g.{{ {firstName: user.firstName, lastName: user.lastName} | formatUserName}}) but this was all thrown out with Polymer 1.0. So sad! Chris

Comment: Justin, yes using a custom input element does seem like the answer. The prefix and suffix don't seem all that useful for my particular use cases.

Comment: Well you can even build your own custom input.